# Grab Email using node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, node.js-connect

I am new to node.js where in my requirement is to ***grab received email subject, attachment and email body*** using **node.js** I am not able to find any solutions. Can anyone suggest me what kind of approach I should take.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that nodemailer only permits to send mail (if I m not wrong).

You should use a librarie that allow you to receive message, like using POP3 protcole (https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=pop3)

Comment: How I will use this module?